# wired issue with testing app in different devices

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I develop an android app, and now I'm in the last steps. I want to check my apps in different devices.
The app combines read from/write to Firebase server.
I checked the app in 2 different Meizu devices (M2,M3s) - the app behaves exactly as I expected. 
I checked the app in Samsung Galaxy S8 - the method that writes to the server works well - I can see in the server that a new data was inserted.
But somehow i can't see this data on the screen and I suspect that the method of getting the data from the server isn't working well on this device from some reason.

Some important notes:

1. Any user of the app suppose to get only the data that relates to him (according to phone number) but I don't think that this is the problem because as I said  - I checked it with 2 different devices with 2 different users numbers.
2. The scenario of the app is like this: Activity of logo, 2 sec', and automatically goes to -> Main activity, there I have getData() method that suppose to take the phone of the user and print on screen some data of him. 
   3.In Main activity there is a button of write data, there the user write data and it saved in the server without problem, under his number . So I think that the app for sure knows "who is this user".
3. I must say that except that, the app looks the same on Galaxy and Meizu.

Code (I don't think it will help):

```
public void getGroups()
{
    mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReferenceFromUrl("some url xxxxxxxxx/groups");

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.groupsListViewMain);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_view_style, groupsArray );

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    mRootRef.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s)
        {
            final String groupToCheck=dataSnapshot.getKey();

            DatabaseReference mRootRefTemp = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                    .getReferenceFromUrl("some url xxxxxxxxx/users/" + myPhoneNumber+"/");
            mRootRefTemp.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshotSon, String s)
                {
                    //show me only groups that i belong to.
                    if (dataSnapshotSon.child(groupToCheck).getValue() != null)
                    {
                        groupsArrayFullName.add(dataSnapshotSon.child(groupToCheck).getKey().toString());
                        for (DataSnapshot child: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            if (child.getKey().toString().equals("nameOfGroup"))
                            {
                                String value = child.getValue().toString();
                                System.out.println("the child: "+value);
                                groupsArray.add(value);
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println(groupToCheck+" not exists!");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    });
}
```

Please help me!

Comment: update: i added a textView that prints to screen the phone number. Indeed - in samsung galaxy I see null and I can't understand why. One second later I write data into server and he knows my number without problem.

Comment: Try to create and post a [mcve].

Comment: Actually I have nothing special to show. Just a getData() method that goes to server and save to an arrayList all the from there. There, prints it to screen. Works perfect with 2 devices. I investigated deeper and found that the Galaxy DOES behaves the same, but with a small different: It take for him a lot of time to get the data from the server. For example if I refresh the activity and wait about a 40 seconds - I will get my data. That's why I though in the beginning that it doesn't retrieve data at all.

Comment: But now i'm wondering how to solve that problem???